# Addaptive UI based on the scopes the users had access to in App Model V2

Tags: azure

I have application where the user is authentcation using App Model v2. Based on some rules the scopes where the user is requested access for can differ.

I want to have my UI adapted based on the scopes where the user has access to. How do I know to what scopes the user has given consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the access token that you get back from Azure. This contains a claim called "scp". This are the scopes where your user has access to.

If you have the token that you got back (what you add as bearer token) you can use the following method to get back a string[] of the scopes. In your code you can check is the required scope in in the string[] to show or hide some UI:

```
private object GetScopeFromToken(string token)
{
    string[] tokenParts = token.Split('.');
    if (tokenParts.Length < 3)
    {
        return new string[] { };
    }
    string encodedToken = tokenParts[1];

    int leftovers = encodedToken.Length % 4;
    if (leftovers == 2)
    {
        encodedToken += "==";
    }
    else if (leftovers == 3)
    {
        encodedToken += "=";
    }
    encodedToken = encodedToken.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
    var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedToken);
    string decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    dynamic jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(decodedToken);
    return jwt.scp.Value.Split(' ');
}
```